# C# application not running on startup

Tags: c#, windows, startup

I can't for the life of me figure this one out. I have created a fairly large C# application that basically runs a bunch of separate components and reboots the machine periodically. The idea of this application is basically to automate a process that we have at my company. So I had it working previously so that after the machine reboots it launches after an account is logged into.

Anyways the app no longer will launch on startup. Please see the code below which  I have implemented to add an entry to the **Run** key in the registry:

```
RegistryKey winStartUpKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run");
                string shieldStartVal = (string)winStartUpKey.GetValue("SHIELDCustomizer");
                if (shieldStartVal == null)
                {
                    string currentName = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
                    string currentDIR = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\" + currentName;
                    RegistryKey startUpKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey
                        (@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
                    startUpKey.SetValue("SHIELDCustomizer", "\"" + currentDIR + "\"", RegistryValueKind.String);
                }
```

The above code has worked in the past. And I have verified that the startup entry is in-fact added to the registry. When I copy the path in the registry into a run prompt and click OK, the app starts without an issue.

I have made some small changes to the code (rather lengthy code, not sure where to begin posting this code) that I can't imagine having an impact on whether or not the app launches on startup. All of my images and files have been added as a resource to the project. The only reference I could really find that outlined this similar scenario is on this forum here: [application won't start on startup after adding a notifyicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137300/application-wont-start-on-startup-after-adding-a-notifyicon) which actually doesn't look like it pertains to my current setup because my notifyIcon object and properties have been added using Visual Studio and I have not coded it manually.

Does anyone have any idea as to what might be causing a program to not launch at startup when the correct entry is in the registry? I know I haven't provided much code, please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide and I will be happy to do so.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Did you do something that requires administrative privileges? Update to your anti-virus that could be sand-boxing the app?

Comment: Or do you need to use a service who didn't started when your application tried to use it ?

Comment: is your AV blocking it?....

Comment: What kind of C# application is it ? Winforms / Console / WPF ?

Comment: Is this a server, or a user machine?

Comment: Hey guys thank you for all of your quick responses. My AV is not blocking it (Microsoft Security Essentials). The app runs when I double click it normally. I have tested with both UAC disabled and enabled. I have tested on both Windows 7 x86 an x64 bit machines as well as a Windows 8 x64 machine. This is a Windows forms app. None of the tests were performed on servers, but WIndows Professional PCs.

Comment: How do you check whether it runs or not? Could it be that it runs, but terminates immediately?

Comment: @n0rd that's a great question haha I have tried to fire up task manager as quickly as possible once the profile loads but I haven't observed the process running at all. I will give event logs a check and I'm pretty sure there is a startup diagnostic utility out there which can monitor startup activity

Answer (score 0):

Startup Tasks can be disabled using Task Manager in Windows 8.1 or msconfig in Windows 7.  For example, I have disabled Box Sync from running at startup on my machine:

[image]

Enabling/Disabling though task manager sets a registry key at

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run`

or

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run`

If the value starts with `02 00 00` then it is enabled.  If it starts with another value (like `03 00` in my example) then it is disabled:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your advice John, I have verified that the app is enabled in both the registry and task manager / msconfig in both WIndows 7 and Windows 8, still with no luck. I think the problem here lies with something in the application. I just can't imagine what it is.

Comment: Seems that different versions of Windows have different flags for disabled programs. For example, on my Win8.1 I have all zeros for enabled program and "01 00 00 ..." for disabled program.

Comment: @VictorMezrin perhaps the first bit specifies whether the entry is disabled, and the other bits contain some other data