# How to enable/disable Windows startup items programmatically?

Tags: windows, winapi, startup

I know that startup items themselves are defined in registry `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.

This can be altered with win32 to add/remove startup items.

But what I can't figure out is how to enable/disable these items?

Entries under `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` do not have enable/disable flag.

How can I enable/disable startup items with win32?

Comment: [Where are disabled autostart programs stored? Somewhere in the registry?](https://superuser.com/questions/664641/where-are-disabled-autostart-programs-stored-somewhere-in-the-registry)

Comment: There is no API to manipulate the startup items. To remove an item you just delete the value from the registry key. [Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) for example moves the deleted values to `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\AutorunsDisabled` in order to remember what was removed and allow for restoring them.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708700/winapi-and-programs-in-startup-locations-disabled-by-user):

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApp‌​roved\Run contains records with binary data for disabled programs. This data accessed and edited via regular WinAPI calls.

So you can try to change the registry information to achieve this function.

Some code for your reference:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HKEY key;
    BOOL fResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\StartupApproved\\Run", 0, KEY_WRITE, &key);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == fResult)
    {
        DWORD dwData[] = { 0x2,0x0,0x0 };
        if (RegSetValueEx(key, __TEXT("OneDrive"), 0, REG_BINARY, (LPBYTE)&dwData, sizeof(dwData)))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return fResult;
}
```

If you want to disable this function, you only need to modify the code to `dwData = 0x03`.

More references: [Configuring an installer to enable/disable startup on Windows start](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b4c9f990-ecb5-46e1-9711-df72bb896f31/configuring-an-installer-to-enabledisable-startup-on-windows-start?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) , [C# application not running on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994315/c-sharp-application-not-running-on-startup/29994809#29994809)

Comment: Hi, does the answer solve your issue? Please feel free to let me know if you have any issue and also accept it if it does help.

Answer (score 1):

So I noticed by changing values from following the reg path we can actually enable/disable apps (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run)
But the question is do we have a PowerShell script to input those values remotely when we start the windows...Assitance needed.